# Taking the return value of a function and changing it into an int python

Tags: python, function, return-value

```
shopping_list = []

  def show_help():
    print("\nSeperate each item with a comma.")
    print("Type DONE to quit, SHOW to see the current list, and Help to get this message again.")

  def show_list():
    count=1
    for item in shopping_list:
      print("{}: {}".format(count, item))
      count += 1

  print("Give me a list of things you want to add to the list.")
  show_help()

  while True:
    new_stuff = input("> ")

    if new_stuff == "DONE":
      print ("\n Here's your list:")
      show_list()
      break
    elif new_stuff == "HELP":
      show_help()
      continue
    elif new_stuff == "SHOW":
      show_list()
      continue
    else:
      new_list = new_stuff.split(",")
      def spot_in():
        index = input("Add this item at a certain spot? Press enter to place it at end of list, "
                      "or give me a mumber. Currently {} items in the   list.".format(
         len(shopping_list)))
        return index

      if spot_in():
        try:
          spot = int(spot_in()) - 1
        except ValueError:
          print ("That's not a number, trying to cheat eh? Enter a real number")
          put_in()
        for item in new_list:
          shopping_list.insert(spot, item.strip())
          spot += 1
      else:
        for item in new_list:
          shopping_list.append(item.strip())
```

My problem is that as far as I know the only way to make sure the location is a number is to use a try and expect with a function inside it. But the code throws an error when I try to turn the return value of the function into an int.

Is there a better way to make sure the return number is an int? OR is there some other way to turn the function's return value into an int?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the isdigit() function for strings which will return True if it is a number, and false if it has a character or is empty.

Comment: after about a minute of testing, I found out the error was actually from me misspelling a function name, but this may come in handy for future readers so I'll leave it up.